# What is the difference between on-the-go, save episode and download episode?

Tags: iphone, podcasts.app

When using the podcast app, I can view the details about a particular show and am presented with three options that all sound like what I want to do. I want to get the episode now over wifi, and then listen to the episode later with no data connection.

What is the difference between on-the-go, save episode and download episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On-The-Go** will create a play list which can be found under **My Stations / On-The-Go**.

**Save Episode** will save an episode that **you've already played** under the *Saved* tab.

Doing **Download Episode**, on the other hand, will actually start to download the episode and move it into *My Podcasts* list.

So, while *On-The-Go* and *Save Episode* is a way of *organizing* the episodes you've already downloaded, doing *Download Episode* actually downloads it.